# GEE - "NDVI" is not defined in this scope

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE and Javascript. I'm trying to perform a simple task: calculate and visualize NDVI for January 2010 from Landsat 7. This is my code:

```
//Load January 2010 Data
var January = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_RT")
.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-01-31');
var ls_January = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(January);
var comp_January = ls_January.normalizedDifference(['B4', 
'B3']).rename('NDVI');
var NDVI_January = comp_January.select('NDVI');

var ndviVis  = {
min: 0.0,
max: 8000.0,
palette: [
'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
'66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
'012E01', '011D01', '011301'
],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(NDVI, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
```

The error message reads "NDVI is not defined in this scope.
in , line 32
in , line 34"

I only have about 20 lines of code and made sure all blank space is deleted...

One fix I tried was to change how NDVI is calculated using GEE's own example. While this appeared to have resolved the previous error message that "NDVI is not defined in this scope," I doubt it's correct because my final map is blank. This is the modified code.

```
var January = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_RT")  
.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-01-31');
var ls_January = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite(January);

var addNDVI = function(image) {
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
var NDVI = addNDVI(ls_January).select('NDVI') 

var ndviVis  = {
min: 0.0,
max: 8000.0,
palette: [
'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
'66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
'012E01', '011D01', '011301'
],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(NDVI, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you have quoted in your question cannot produce the error message "not defined in this scope", so the problem must be in some other version or part of your code. Please [edit] your question to include a section of code which you have made sure actually produces the scope error when run _by itself_ in the Earth Engine Code Editor.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I edited my question to include all of my code and still received a similar error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var NDVI_January = comp_January.select('NDVI');
...
Map.addLayer(NDVI, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
```

The first version of your code does not work because you have not defined a *variable* named `NDVI`. Probably you want to write `NDVI_January` instead.

```js
Map.addLayer(NDVI_January, ndviVis, 'NDVI');
```

Variable names are not the same as band names. Variable names never appear in quotes — they are only defined by `var`, function parameter lists, or imports.

---

Your second script is producing all white output because your visualization `max` is way too high, so only the first palette entry is being used. I determined this by using the **Inspector** tab in the code editor: click on it, then click somewhere on the map, and you can find out what the numerical value of the bands under that pixel are.

Change `max: 8000.0,` to `max: 1.0,` and you will be able to see some data. Then adjust it further it to suit the palette usage you're looking for.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for not only fixing my code but explaining the where and why.